# Ellipsis overflow with background box

Tags: css

I get that you can't use overflow: hidden with inline elements. So how would I get text that looks like this:

[image]

and this when it's longer:

[image]

When I have this the overflow doesn't work:

```
.box-text {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 4px;
  display: inline;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

and if I change display: inline to display: block the box stretches the full width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the best of both worlds -- `display: inline-block;`, and set a width:

```
.box-text {
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 4px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:50px
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9uh4Ltxf/)**

Comment: Any way without a fixed width or is that a must?

Comment: @user2736480 use max-width instead of width

Answer (score 1):

You should set the width of the div of the width. It can't just guess the width to stop on and start an ellipsis. You can do something like this:

```
.box-text {
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 4px;
    display: inline;
    text-overflow: ellipsis; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```